# Vagrant and Virtual Box both installed still my vagrant up command giving path error

Tags: powershell, vagrant, virtualbox, git-bash, vagrantfile

I am using git bash and vagrant file is already added to my project but when I am trying to run VAGRANT UP command it gives this error :

```
$ vagrant up
The executable 'powershell' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the %PATH% variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.
```

Help me to fix this.

The vagrant file contains:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved my issue was the a comment I found by **antoinebou13** [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/363#issuecomment-586745607)

PC: WSL ubuntu 18.04
Windows 10 with installed vagrant 2.2.7 and virtualbox 6.1

```
curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.7/vagrant_2.2.7_x86_64.deb
sudo apt install ./vagrant_2.2.7_x86_64.deb
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox"
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0"
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32"
export VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS="1"
```

Also put your project in the /mnt/c/ directory
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/wsl.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a simple CMD session, check your path:

```
echo %PATH%
```

It should at least include `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

It depends on your OS and execution context.
For instance, [mitchellh/vagrant-aws issue 363](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/363#issuecomment-315194696) mentions:

> I had this problem when running vagrant up from a Cygwin Terminal using zsh.
>
> I got Vagrant 1.9.7 to work by appending the path to `powershell.exe` to my `PATH`.
> In `.zshrc`:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0"
```

Comment: @Voc's    Man i already added it to my path then too i cannot find any solution

Comment: @ApurvaGeete What does echo %PATH% gives you?

Comment: %systemroot%c:/windows/poweshell/v1.0  is the path that i have specified in in my env variables

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from a network disconnection and the server re-sets the connection to the client, messing up the original SSL handshake.

Just make sure the connection is stable and re-run the command:

```
$ vagrant up
```

It will restart and complete the download.